# CefSharp WinForms browser hosted within WPF WinFormsHost

Tags: c#, cefsharp

I'm currently working on moving out kiosk software that runs Awesomium away and instead onto CefSharp.
Our main application is written in WPF and this work is using v45 of CefSharp

I'm aware that the WPF control has some serious performance issues, when compared side-by-side with the WinForms version hosted in a WindowsFormsHost, the smoothness of transitions etc is MUCH better.

To that end I'm looking to stick with this approach of embedding the WinForms ChromiumWebBrowser inside a WindowsFormsHost on the WPF window. This all works and however I'm having issues with getting touch support to work.
Our kiosks have touch screens and run Windows 7 / 8.1, the touch works flawlessly with the WPF control, however when using the WinForms embedded one touch doesn't work at-all.
As well as touch not working it also steals all Keyboard events and consumes them internally it seems, as none of my event handlers ever fire on the main WPF window.

If anyone has any ideas or can point me in the correct direction to try and solve this it would be hugely appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The scenario your talking about is not well supported and as such there is not a lot of information. A lot of the problem your are seeing are likely because `CEF` is running it's message loop in a separate thread. If you turn `MultiThreadedMessageLoop` off, then you become responsible for calling `Cef.DoMessageLoopWork()`. I recently added a rough demo the `WinForms Example`. You can likely port this to `WPF`, though I've never tried.

- https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/cefsharp/45/CefSharp.Example/CefExample.cs#L76
- https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/cefsharp/45/CefSharp.WinForms.Example/Program.cs#L37

You are in somewhat uncharted territory there, so you'll have to do most of the leg work yourself.

For reference there are some ways to improve the `WPF` performance. They come with their own set of drawbacks though. See https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/cefsharp/45/CefSharp.Example/CefExample.cs#L58

Comment: Thanks for the reply!
I've tried those WPF performance improvement and they do have an effect, a very good noticeable one in-fact. The problem is when you then test that side-by-side to WinForms on it's own or hosted inside WPF, the speed there seems leaps and bounds above again.

I'll have a look into seeing if I can get the various bits about the message loop and your example to work with WPF and If I have any luck then I'll let you know.

Comment: So running it in a WinFormsHost and then explicitly calling DoMessageLoopWork() seems to solve part of the problem. Doing this allows input events to fire up in the WPF layer, so my shortcut to open dev tools and other application specific things now all work. Is there any way I can inject some of these events into the CefSharp browser as a touch event? The only vaguely related method I can see is SendMouseWheelEvent.

Comment: Nothing out of the box, touch support has not been implemented upstream. See https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/issues/1059/cef3-multi-touch-support-with-offscreen and https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/pull/1418

Comment: Ah I thought I saw something about that in my searches, in that case do you think it would be feasible to route touch "clicks" through as simple mouse clicks? I don't see why that wouldn't work, I just need to work out how/where to inject or map the events.

Comment: You can likely post `WP_Touch` messages https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317341%28v=vs.85%29.aspx